# MySQL: from_unixtime: Access denied

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to run following query from the PHP:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_customer
WHERE (date_format(from_unixtime(survey_submit_date),'%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-03-01') OR
   (date_format(from_unixtime(survey_submit_date),'%Y-%m-%d') = '2017-12-01')
```

However, it is giving an error as:

> Access denied near field (from_unixtime(survey_submit_date)

I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone know this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the calls to `DATE_FORMAT`, because `FROM_UNIXTIME` already takes a format mask as its second parameter.  I expect the following query to work:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_customer
WHERE
    FROM_UNIXTIME(survey_submit_date, '%Y-%m-%d') IN ('2018-03-01', '2017-12-01');
```

I have never seen your exact error before, though if the above does not work then maybe you should check things like permissions and access rights.

Comment: If I run the following query then it executes perfectly fine:

SELECT *
FROM data_customer
WHERE from_unixtime(survey_submit_date) = '2018-03-01' OR
   from_unixtime(survey_submit_date) = '2017-12-01'

But as soon as I add '%Y-%m-%d', it gives Access denied error.

Comment: @Trupti Very strange.  I think there is some permissions issue going on.  Anyway, at least you have a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you don't have permission to fetch the column -> **survey_submit_date**

Run the below query to check current user's permission:

**`show grants;`**

Comment: I can fetch survey_submit_date...as I said eariler, as soon as I add '%Y-%m-%d', it gives Access denied error

Comment: what's the mysql version ?

Comment: Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 5.5.56-MariaDB - MariaDB Server